# Аналог бесконечного лета в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать аналог бесконечного лета, дело в том что я не знаю как образовать текст при нажатии. Пример: Нажимаю кнопку далее и появляется новый текст. Как не создавать каждый раз новую панель с текстом, а просто через код при нажатии менялся текст.

Если вы вдруг не поняли что я хочу: Что бы был код который бы я закинул на объект, и там была панель где бы я писал текст с каждым названием панель...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнëм с того, что для этого нужен особый `List<string>` со всеми фразами.

Для теста сделай класс `DialogueController`, у которого будет этот самый `List<string> с именем _phrases`, а так же поле с текстом(блоком текста `Text` или `TMP.Text`). Помимо этого сделай int-переменную с названием `_phraseNum`, которое равно -1

Потом создай метод для кнопки. В этом методе добавляй к `_phraseNum` единицу и выводи `_phrases[_phraseNum]` в `Text`

И, удачи, пионер